# What is the meaning that every git repository contains all of the information?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project for my studies, and now I also have a group of students that will be adding functionality to the project. Since I don't trust their changes, I want them to work on a different repository than me (but I am part of their project). My repository is at github, and I also want them to work with github.

The correct (github) way to do this would be to fork the project. But github does not allow me to fork my own project. I tried to forke my own project manually as described [here](http://bitdrift.com/post/4534738938/fork-your-own-project-on-github?7017b280), but while my original project has a number of branches, the new project has only one branch.

What I finally did was to create (locally) a new remote repository (the second github repo) and pushed all my local repo to the new remote repo.

Doing all this I got very confused on the real internals of git. For example: When I clone a new repository I get one master branch which points to the remote's master branch. If I then go and push this local repository to a new remote repository, this remote repo will only have one branch! So how can we say that each git repository contains the same information? What is wrong in my line of though?

Thanks, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: "Since I don't trust their changes" - not the best platform base to build upon!!

Comment: It's not because i don't trust them. It's because they are learning on the go. If I had the time to teach them git (and they had the time to learn) I would surely give them access. But when you don't know how to use a tool you can mess things up really easy. But I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone a git repo, you get the entire repo. Unlike other vcs like SVN in which case you only get a working directory, you get the repo. The reason you don't see any other branches normally is because you don't have local tracking branches for them ( only master is setup by default.) You can see all the branches with `git branch -a` and checkout any branch you want like `git checkout branch`. If you push THIS repo, now you will have the branches.

Comment: The sentence "When you clone a git repo, you get the entire repo" is not completely correct, since you have different branches locally (only the master branch). And if you push to a new repo you get a different history...

Comment: @vainolo - Which is what's explained in the following sentences

Comment: @vainolo - I explained in the next sentence why you don't see all branches, and you ask the same question again

Comment: Hi @manojlds. I understand why I don't see all the branches. Why I didn't get is why this works that way. Now I understand that branches (more correctly branch names) are a concept local to each repository. And that is OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Git book's "[Git Branching](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching)" section. It contains very vital information to understand what branching in git is, and what are remotes branches. Once you understand that, the questions you asked should no longer be unanswered.

Comment: Perhaps you should include a verbatim copy of the commands you have run and their output, and outline where things are working in a way that you don't expect?

Answer (score 0):

After reading again the "[Distributed Git - Distributed Workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows)" chapter of the Git book, I see that my "workflow" is not what I should do. Since I can manage who has access to my repository, I don't need create a new project. The students must clone my repository, do their changes, upload them to their own repository and then I would pull them and merge the changes I like into my repository (also called integrator-manager workflow).